# Need to print data only for selective cases

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

```
<PEE>
 <PG>
   <EMP>

          <Summary>
              <EMP_ID>1</EMP_ID>
          </Summary>

          <PE>
             <Operation>NONE</Operation>
             <AN>100</AN>
         </PE>

          <PE>
             <Operation>REMOVE</Operation>
             <AN>200</AN>
         </PE>

         <PE>
             <Operation>ADD</Operation>
             <AN>300</AN>
         </PE>
  </EMP>

  <EMP>

          <Summary>
              <EMP_ID>2</EMP_ID>
          </Summary>

          <PE>
             <Operation>REMOVE</Operation>
             <AN>400</AN>
         </PE>

          <PE>
             <Operation>NONE</Operation>
             <AN>500</AN>
         </PE>

         <PE>
             <Operation>NONE</Operation>
             <AN>600</AN>
         </PE>

     </EMP>
 </PG>
</PEE>
```

Hello @Michael, thanks a lot for you previous answer. I'm giving you a more proper xml here which is part of the actual xml. Your understanding is correct that no 'REMOVE' operation should be printed in the output and a 'NONE' operation will only be printed if there is at least one 'ADD'/'MODIFY' child operation for the same 'EMP_ID'. I'm expecting 2 rows in the text output where the first row should be '1 NONE 100' and the second one '1 ADD 300'.
Requesting you to help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us the expected output of your example **as code**?

Answer (score 1):

The format of the expected output is not quite clear. The following stylesheet will copy everything as is, except:

1. any `account` whose `action` is "REMOVE";
2. any `account` whose `action` is "NONE" and doesn't have a sibling  `account` whose `action` is either "ADD" or "MODIFY".

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="account[action='REMOVE' or action='NONE' and not(../account[action='ADD' or action='MODIFY'])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input**

```
<root>
  <emp>
    <summary>
      <emp_id>1</emp_id>
    </summary>
    <account>
      <action>REMOVE</action>
      <value>11</value>
    </account>
    <account>
      <action>NONE</action>
      <value>12</value>
    </account>
  </emp>
  <emp>
    <summary>
      <emp_id>2</emp_id>
    </summary>
    <account>
      <action>REMOVE</action>
      <value>21</value>
    </account>
    <account>
      <action>NONE</action>
      <value>23</value>
    </account>
    <account>
      <action>ADD</action>
      <value>22</value>
    </account>
  </emp>
  <emp>
    <summary>
      <emp_id>3</emp_id>
    </summary>
    <account>
      <action>REMOVE</action>
      <value>31</value>
    </account>
    <account>
      <action>NONE</action>
      <value>32</value>
    </account>
    <account>
      <action>MODIFY</action>
      <value>33</value>
    </account>
  </emp>
</root>
```

**Result**

```
<root>
   <emp>
      <summary>
         <emp_id>1</emp_id>
      </summary>
   </emp>
   <emp>
      <summary>
         <emp_id>2</emp_id>
      </summary>
      <account>
         <action>NONE</action>
         <value>23</value>
      </account>
      <account>
         <action>ADD</action>
         <value>22</value>
      </account>
   </emp>
   <emp>
      <summary>
         <emp_id>3</emp_id>
      </summary>
      <account>
         <action>NONE</action>
         <value>32</value>
      </account>
      <account>
         <action>MODIFY</action>
         <value>33</value>
      </account>
   </emp>
</root>
```

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks a lot for your response! This was really helpful. However, I could give the more proper xml for this. Please help me for the same.

Comment: @amit82foru **1.** You still haven't posted your expected output. **2.** I don;t see that there is a big difference between the inputs; why can't you make the necessary adjustments yourself?